# SP.UserProfiles - get all properties available for user

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, userprofiles

Since I do not have access to the SharePoint farm.

Is there any way to retrieve all available property names from UserProfiles in SharePoint 2013 through JavaScript?

What I was looking for is the names you pass as an array with the following call:

```
var object = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(context, accountName, propertyNames);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## From *MSDN*

[Retrieve user profile properties by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx)

```
var personProperties;

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {

    // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
    var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(personProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {

    // Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
    var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_displayName();

    // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
    messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

## Using REST API

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Need to make a **GET** request to the above end point. It will return current user's properties.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I did not know of the method get_userProfileProperties()

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve all the properties, you can use REST api such as:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(targetUsername) + "'&$select=UserProfileProperties";
```

then you can look up all the available properties within 'properties' variable using FireBug/IE dev tool console.

```
var properties = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results; 
window.console && console.log(properties);
```